# That route does not exist! Getting a 404 error when making a sign up form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

im trying to create a signup form by allowing users to enter in their email, password and name. I set up a 404 error code route when a route does not exist and for some reason its going off but i dont know for what reason. Can anyone detect the issue going on. I also have mongodb connected but im not sure if thats affecting it. Heres my code.

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const User = require('../modelSchema/User')

const signUp = (req, res) => {
    
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array()})

        //new instance of user
       const user = new User({ 
        name: req.body.name, 
        email: req.body.email, 
        password: req.body.password })

        //save the user 
      user.save()
      .then(data => {
          response.json(data)
          console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          response.json(err)
      })
   
}


module.exports = { signUp }
```

heres my backend code where im importing mongodb and where my 404 error code is that detects a bad route

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const routes = require('./routes/index')

//middleware
app.use(cors())

dotenv.config()

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log('Database Connected'))

//bodyParser
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.all('*', (req, res) => res.send('That route does not exist!'))

app.use('/app', routes)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is listening on port 4000'))
```

heres where my routes are. for now i just have my signup route but later i will implement a login route

```
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator')
const { signUp } = require('../controllers/users');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', [
    check('name', 'Please Enter your Name').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please Enter your Email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please Enter your Password').isLength({ minLength: 6})
], signUp)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: place`app.all('*', (req, res) => res.send('That route does not exist!'))` after all routes `app.use('/app', routes)` but you should use `app.use((req, res)=>res.send('That route does not exist!'))`

Comment: Thank you for your response. It appears im still getting an error. it reads  "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at /Users/kobesutton/form-practice/server/controllers/users.js:22:11"

Comment: Please see answer below. you were not responding to the request. You used `response` instead of `res`, response is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
const signUp = (req, res) => {
    
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array()})

        //new instance of user
       const user = new User({ 
        name: req.body.name, 
        email: req.body.email, 
        password: req.body.password })

        //save the user 
      user.save()
      .then(data => {
          res.json(data)
          console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).json(err)
      })
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you I don't know how i missed that.